# Are Cloud Endpoints with Go Google App Engine Standard possible?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine-go

I have implemented a simple API in Go on Google App Engine Standard using just:

```
func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/api/v1/resource",submitResource)
}
```

Nothing special. However I want to port this code to using Cloud Endpoints instead in order to get the better monitoring and diagnostics.

Is it even possible with STANDARD instances or must I move to FLEXIBLE?

I can't find any documentation on this. Nor answers to this seemingly simple question. At the moment I half wish I had chosen Python because its support seems more mature. I chose Go because it seems more appropriate for API-like code because my minimal research suggested Go offered better performance.

If it is possible, are there any pointers to how please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research and trial and error, the simple answer is **"No."** - as of Dec 2016.

The longer answer is it's possible if you want to put far too much effort into making up to date libraries of your own. There is basically no support, even in alpha, for the **current** Google Cloud Endpoints using **Go** with Google App Engine **Standard**.

Answer (score 2):

Only Python and Java are supported on GAE Standard via the Endpoints Frameworks. However, Go is supported on GAE Flexible.

Here is the Go GAE Flexible sample:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/endpoints/getting-started

Comment: That isn't "Google cloud endpoints". That sample example uses https://github.com/gorilla/mux which is just a go library for apis. Don't expect that to handle users, api explorers, api keys, discovery, multiple backends/frontends etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to run Go+endpoints on GAE Standard environment, however libraries might be outdated now.
Libraries and sample app can be found on github:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/go-endpoints
I have successfully deployed "Greetings" as AppEngine SE app, and it works.

Comment: It's possible but libraries might be outdated.... I.e. it's not possible in any useful way.