# Google endpoint in Golang standard Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-endpoints

I have developed an application using Google App Engine's Standard environment in Golang. Now I want to use Google Endpoint to use the same backhand for developing Android and IOS app. However, it seeps google do not support endpoint in golang standard environment.

Is there a work around for this without actually getting into Flexi environment? I am afraid that if I have to move into Flexi Environment then I had to rewrite lot of code.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstarts-app-engine-standard

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://godoc.org/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/go-endpoints/endpoints

Comment: No.. this you cant use in standard environment. It doesn't work. Please let me know if somehow you managed it to work. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Cloud Endpoints with Go Google App Engine Standard possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513743/are-cloud-endpoints-with-go-google-app-engine-standard-possible)

Comment: Sadly, I think the answer is currently No.

Comment: @ChrisDrew what about these examples?
 https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/go-endpoints  https://github.com/googlesamples/cloud-polymer-go